# How to find roots of a complex function with python?

Tags: python, sympy, mpmath

I'm working with a complex function whose coordinate is `omega`. I formed it as follows:

```
from sympy import *

def alpha(n, rho, l):
     return n**2 + (2*rho + 2)*n + 2*rho + 1

def beta(n, rho, l):
     return -(2*n**2 + (8*rho + 2)*n + 8*rho**2 + 4*rho + l*(l+1) -3)

def gamma(n, rho, l):
     return n**2 + 4*rho*n + 4*rho**2 - 4

def ContinuedFrac(n, rho, l):
     cf = 0
     for i in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
         cf = cf + beta(i, rho, l)/alpha(i, rho, l)
         cf = (-gamma(i, rho, l)/alpha(i, rho, l)) / cf
     return cf
```

And I would like to find the roots for which the function `ContinuedFrac` is equal to `beta(0, i*omega, 3)/alpha(0, i*omega, 3)` and admits the values n=3, rho = i*omega and l=3. I tried to find the roots using the `findroot` function from the `mpmath` library:

```
from sympy import *
import mpmath as mp

omega = symbols("ω")

f = ContinuedFrac(1, i*omega, 3) + beta(0, i*omega, 3)/alpha(0, I*omega, 3)
findroot(f, 2-0.5j)
```

where `2-0.5j` is an initial values that is needed for convergence. I wanted an answer like (1.198 - 0.185 i) but the result was an error (photo below). What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please show one complete sample of code that reproduces what you show. The code shown fails with `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`.

Comment: Yes, please extract and provide a [mcve]. Don't use images of text either, they can't be copied and executed (for code) or searched (for error messages). As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: looks like `findroot` wants a `function` argument, not the result of a function call.  You've given it a sympy expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you used `i` to indicate the imaginary number, but in SymPy it is `I`.

The reason you see that error is because `findroot` requires a numerical function, but you passed in a symbolic expression. You could use `lambdify` to convert `f` to a numerical function, but we can get away with a different procedure instead.

You could try to use `solve` or `solveset`, but it is not guaranteed that they find all roots. For example:

```py
sol = solve(f, omega)
sol = [s.n() for s in sol]
for s in sol:
    print(s)
# out:
# -0.92071676505822 + 0.74526156471082*I
# 0.92071676505822 + 0.74526156471082*I
# 1.13988532510002 + 0.19223843528918*I
# -1.13988532510002 + 0.19223843528918*I
```

In this case, we can create a 3D plot with the magnitude of the function and verify that all zeros have been found. To do that, I'm going to use [this plotting module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
from spb import *
l = 2
plot_complex(log(f), (omega, -l-l*1j, l+l*1j), n=500,
             zlabel="log(abs(f))", threed=True, backend=KB)
```

[image]

The downward spikes are the zeros. The upward spikes are the poles. We can count 4 zeros, which match what `solve` found.

Now, let's talk about SymPy's `nsolve` (numerical solver), which is going to use mpmath's `findroot`: by providing appropriate initial guesses, we can use `nsolve` to find the roots. To find appropriate initial guesses, I'm going to plot the magnitude of the complex function:

```py
p1 = plot_complex(f, (omega, -l-l*1j, l+l*1j), {"interpolation": "spline36"},
    coloring="e", grid=False, n=1000)
```

[image]

These zebra-stripes represents the magnitude: they are circling around the zeros and poles. In this kind of plot, we can't distinguish between them, however we can obtain a initial guess for `nsolve`. For example:

```py
s1 = nsolve(f, omega, -1+0.25j)
s2 = nsolve(f, omega, 1+0.25j)
s3 = nsolve(f, omega, -0.9+0.75j)
s4 = nsolve(f, omega, 0.9+0.75j)
p2 = plot_complex_list([s1, s2, s3, s4], {"marker": "^", "color": "r"}, show=False)
(p1 + p2).show()
```

[image]

This last picture overlays the solutions to the previous plot. If you try to use `nsolve`, you'll soon discover that it is very sensitive to the initial guess, in particular for complex functions where, as you can see from the 3D plot, the spatial distance between a zero and a pole might be very small. This means that saddle points might force the algorithm to fall into the same root even with very different initial guesses.